# How to save the new data to existing cell?

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data, swift3, ios10

How can I save the time to existing cell?

Page 1 have name, phone number, company, job number..

Because the time is in the page 2, I don't know how do save it easily.
Anybody can help me solve this problem? thanks soooo much!!!!

```
NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1570.), NSValidationErrorObject=<VisitorMO: 0x60000009c570> (entity: Visitor; id: 0x600000221800 <x-coredata:///Visitor/t47C35BF8-213C-4C00-9B86-DDF5B423B9092> ; data: {
    company = nil;
    jobnumber = nil;
    jobtype = nil;
    name = nil;
    phonenumber = nil;
    signintime = "May 30, 2017, 2:10:23 PM";
})}
)
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand your question? Do you want to transfer data from one view controller to another? Or do you want to reload the cells once you get the data in existing tableview?

Comment: Hi Anil Kukadeja, Thank you for your help.
In fact,I want to update the new information to existing cell.
There is a cell in it. (this cell have "name" and "time" , but it just have name now ). it missing time.
so I want to add the time to this cell.

Comment: You want to update collectionview or tableview view?

Comment: just want to update the tableview view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to update existing cell's data..

You can do few things..

**First** `yourTableview.reloadData()` call this method.

This will reload your tableview.

**Second** if you want to update existing cell..

```
yourTableview.beginUpdates()
yourTableview.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
yourTableview.endUpdates()
```

Here indexPath will be your index which you want to update.

**Third** update specific cell

```
let indexPathYouWantToUpdate = IndexPath(row:Any row which you want to update,section:0)

let cell = yourTableview.cellForRowAtIndex(at:indexPathYouWantToUpdate) as? YourCustomCell

cell?.value1 = 100
cell?.value2 = 200
```

update all the cell values the way you want.

I hope this solves your question here.

Comment: @Gordon : Did you checked my answer?